# Proving the supremum of set

Tags: real-analysis

Use Archimedean Property to prove that sup$\lbrace \cos(\frac{1}{n}): n \in \mathbb{N} \rbrace = 1$. (Use the fact that $\cos x > x - x^2/2$ for $x \neq 0$

Observe that $\cos 1 \in A$ and $|A| < 2$, so by Axiom of Completeness, this set has a supremum. Let $\alpha = \sup A$. Assume $\alpha > 1$. I'm stuck after this point, any guidance would be appreciated.

Comment: I imagine you mean $\ge 1-{x^2 \over 2}$...

Comment: You would like to show that $1 = \sup(A)$, i.e. that $1$ is the least upper bound to the set.  This requires that you show two things: first, that $1$ is an upper-bound of $A$ (i.e. $a \leq 1$ for all $a \in A$).
Second, that $1$ is the least among upper bounds.  A convenient formulation of this condition is as follows. For any $\epsilon > 0$, there exists an $a \in A$ such that $a \geq 1 - \epsilon$.